# View Tomcat Application Logfile in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, logging, netbeans, log4j, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 for deploying my WebApplication on a Tomcat. When I run/deploy the application, I can see the the Server Log and the "Apache Tomcat Log" in the Output Window.

But in my application I specified with log4j another Logfile for my application logs only.

**How can I see the Log of my Application like the other Log Output directly in Netbeans?**

[image]

My log4j has the specification of an additional log - so all warning/error of my classes will be appended there.

```
###### My Log
log4j.appender.myLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myLog.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myLog.log
log4j.appender.myLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.myLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.myDomain=WARN, myLog
```

Answer (score 2):

First you find service option. Then stop the tomcat service and restart it. Then you can see you tomcat log file in output view bar:

[image: output view bar]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the service option where you can find the database and servers etc. Select Services-Servers-Tomact-start. This show you the Tomact log data.